# $watch on form element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm trying to implement real time search so i have a search for including many input fields 
so each and every time when user update input fields search function should be triggered.

i have came up with $watch to track model changes on form field

```
$scope.$watch('filters.site', function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('updateDataTable');
});
$scope.$watch('filters.fname', function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('updateDataTable');
});
$scope.$watch('filters.lname', function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('updateDataTable');
});
```

but i'm just wondered is there anyway to get whole form value changes

my form look like

```
<form name="searchForm">
    <label for="">FIRST NAME</label>
    <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            data-ng-model="filters.fname">
    <span></span>
    <label for="">LAST NAME</label>
    <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            data-ng-model="filters.lname">
    <span></span>
    <label for="">SITE</label>
    <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            data-ng-model="filters.site">
    <span></span>
</form>
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `true` as the last argument to `$watch`, Angular will watch for deep equality instead, and you can watch the entire object at once:

```
$scope.$watch("filters", function() { ... }, true);
```

That will incur creating a copy of the object on every digest cycle, but if all your filters object contains is those filters, it's probably not going to be any more inefficient than watching everything separately. If your filters object is expensive to copy for some reason you could also use a $watchGroup for equivalent functionality to your current code except neater:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(["filters.site", "filters.fname", ...], function() { ... });
```

Comment: brilliant that would be the exact solution thanks Matti

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$watch('filters', function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('updateDataTable');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ng-change directive that could call your search function just add it on all your input so when one of the input change the search function will be called.

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-change="search()" data-ng-model="filters.fname">
```